# Android Air App very large on install?

Tags: android, air, size, installation

I have just developed a new Android Air application using Adobe Flashbuilder and I am having the issue that when it is installed on a device it is 10mb in size which is huge. I dont understand why this is as when I look at the size of the entire App Folder in Flashbuilder it only ammounts to 1.6mb.

Is there something that I should have done within Flashbuilder in order to compress the size? Can anyone please help with this as I really want to release this app but dont want to at this install size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 MB is really not that much.

But it's probably because you're using a third party library and that's not inside your folder but it needs to be compiled within your app.